# Report AJAX error to php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, error-reporting

I use several jQuery AJAX calls in my application and sometimes encounter errors during those AJAX calls such as 500 internal server error. To get to the bottom of the error, I log into the server and check the error log which provides me with the PHP error.

I'm looking for a way to get notifications when these errors happen and what the PHP error was that caused the error. At least a way to get notified instead of having to receive an email from an user and then go in and check the logs.

I checked out this tutorial but am not sure how to integrate this into the AJAX error: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-email-error-logs-to-yourself-with-php/ and also I'm not sure if this will return the PHP error or just the 500 internal server error.

Any ideas, existing services, or solutions are greatly appreciated! Here is one of my AJAX calls for example:

```
$.ajax ({
        url: report,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            // continue with event
        },
        error: function(x, status, error) {
            // report error here
        },
        async:true
});
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the updated AJAX call that makes an AJAX requests to the php error notification...

```
$.ajax ({
        url: report,
        success: function(html) {
            // success
        },
        error: function(x, status, error) {
            $.ajax ({
                url: 'admin/error_notification.php',
                type: "POST",
                data:{
                    error: error
                }
            });
        },
        async:true
});
```

This works great, however, only reports that an internal server error occurred instead of the actual PHP error that caused the AJAX error. Here is the PHP error handling file:

```
$error = $_POST['error'];
$sysadmin_message = $error;
$sysadmin_to = 'email@example.com';
$sysadmin_subject = 'Error Notification';
$sysadmin_headers = "From: Site <accounts@example.com>\r\n";
$sysadmin_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$sysadmin_headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($sysadmin_to, $sysadmin_subject, $sysadmin_message, $sysadmin_headers);
```

Obviously this will only send the AJAX error reported, but how do I add the actually PHP error to the notification?

Comment: is display_errors set to "On" in your php.ini file?

Comment: if not, you might want to set it to "On", and then set the error reporting level on each non-ajax page so that errors aren't shown to users

Comment: I still think a try/catch would be a better solution though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make a second ajax call inside of the error function to report to php

From the front end:

```
$.ajax ({
        url: report,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            // continue with event
        },
        error: function(x, status, error) {
            // report error here
            $.ajax ({
                url: errorlogUrl,
                data:{
                    message:'ajax error from [report]'
                }
            });
        },
        async:true
});
```

Or use a try/catch statement on the backend:

```
try{
    // code that might throw an error
}
catch(Exception $e){
    // send notification based on the content of $e
}
```

Comment: This is great, however, if I set it to send the error, it's only reporting that an internal server error occurred. I still need to then check the log files for the actual PHP error. Is there anyway to get the PHP error upon the AJAX error?

Comment: not if the server is returning a HTTP 500. You can change your php.ini file to displayErrors = On, and it will show you the actual error. Only do that in a dev environment though, not a good idea for production. Why not just use php's error log?

Comment: Sorry jsut re-read your question. You could also try catching fatal errors in php with a try catch block, then sending yourself the notification in the catch. Updated my answer